# How to handle "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'"

Tags: python, runtime-error, tinydb

I want to set up a new tinyDB object in Python 3, but TinyDB() gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Utente/Documents/CodingStuff/AlgManager/AlgManager.py", line 4, in <module>
    db = tdb.TinyDB()
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\prova\venv\lib\site-packages\tinydb\database.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._storage = storage(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

I guess it's something about installation, because the code I wrote is really only

```
import tinydb as tdb

db = tdb.TinyDB()
```

I installed TinyDB with pip.
What can I do?

Comment: See answer below, and btw [read (always) the docs](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what python version you use TinyDB has a required parameter "path to db" when you create the instance.

Something like this:

```
import tinydb as tdb
db = tdb.TinyDB('path/to/db.json')
```